# Python subprocess column invalid option

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I want to ask the shell to display a `csv` file in a nice format in my python script. So I wrote the following:

```
printout = "column -s, -t < output.csv | less -#2 -N -S "
subprocess.call(printout.split(), shell = False)
```

The error I get is:

```
column: invalid option -- '#'
```

I have a rough idea that it is something to do with `shell=False`; however when I set it to `True` and run in cmd line, it puts me into another line and I have to `ctrl+C` to get out.

Comment: `shell=False` means you don't have a shell, so there's nothing that knows how to process redirections (`<`) or pipes (`|`). It's actually *better* to use `shell=False`, but it means you need to do more of your setup in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code was equivalent to the shell command:

```
# this can be used to reproduce your bug at a shell
column -s, -t '<' output.csv '|' less -#2 -N -S
```

...passing `<`, `|`, `less`, etc. as arguments to `column`, not treating them as shell directives.

---

See the section [Replacing Shell Pipelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) in the `subprocess` module documentation.

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['column', '-s,', '-t'],
                      stdin=open('output.csv', 'r'),
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['less', '-#2', '-N', '-S'],
                      stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close() # ensure that p2 has the only remaining handle on p1.stdout
p2.communicate()  # let less run
```

Comment: Why we need separate list entry like 'column','-s,'...can we use it instead like 'column -s -t'? Or what is the advantage of former approach

Comment: @pankajmishra, the advantage of this approach is that you're not relying on a shell to do the splitting for you. This is very much better practice, because something like `split()` or even `shlex.split()` can be intentionally misled or broken by unexpected or malicious filenames -- think about what happens if your `output.csv` is from a variable and the filename has a space in it.

Comment: OMG! Thank you SOOOOOO MUUUCH

Comment: @pankajmishra, ...some folks will somewhat naively use quoting like `"'%s'" % filename` with `shlex.split()` or `shell=True`, but even that doesn't work if the filename contains literal `'`s that can then escape the syntactical ones.

Comment: @pankajmishra, ...and the other point is that a list of strings is actually the native format for an argv list at the operating system level -- the way other programs are started on UNIX is with the `execve` syscall, and it takes a list of C strings. Anything you do with a *single* string instead of a list is going to need to be broken down / transformed into that list before it can actually be used; passing a list yourself means you have absolutely control, instead of relying on whatever does that transformation to do it the way you intend.

Comment: Thanks Charles,nice explanation..it cleared my doubt.